# Windows Service em execução não conecta no banco

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service

Boa tarde pessoal. Criei uma solution em 3 camadas para um projeto de windows services. Em debug consigo buscar a informações de banco e fazer os processos com o retorno.
Porem, quando coloco o processo para rodar nos serviços do windows não funciona. Criei log para saber onde esta com o erro e é justamente onde busca as informações de banco, ou seja, no App.config.

Estou desconfiado que ao fazer o comando installutil para coloca-lo nos processos não esta indo junto as dll's do projeto Business e Data.

Alguem ja teve esse problema?

Comment: As `dlls` devem ficar no mesmo diretório do executável, desconfio que suas `dlls` da camada de dados não estão lá. Copie todas as `dlls` dos projetos para a pasta do executável.

Comment: O pior é que elas estão na mesma pasta. Para garantir ainda, peguei todas elas e coloquei em outra pasta e refiz o processo. E mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Tem certeza que todas as `dlls` referenciadas no projeto estão lá? Outro detalhe o arquivo `App.config` também deve está nesta pasta, ele vai ficar com o nome do seu `executável`ou seja, se seu executável for `MeuApp.exe`  a sua configuração será `MeuApp.exe.config`

Comment: Sim sim... Certeza absoluta. :-(

Comment: E quanto ao arquivo `MeuApp.exe.config` estão com as configurações corretas de conexão?

Comment: Sim, tanto que em modo debug consigo acessar as informações de banco normalmente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34564/discussion-between-rubstackoverflow-and-luciano-carlos).